# Select distinct elements in listview when click item

Tags: java, android

I have a list view with custom adapter, with an Image Button and a Text View.

I want to open a context menu when a press is made on the Image Button, and open another context menu if i press the Text View.

How can I do this??

This is my onClickListener

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (id == view.findViewById(R.id.label).getId()) //label press
            {
                TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
                registerForContextMenu(text);
                openContextMenu(text);
            }
            else //imageButton press
            {
                ImageButton ib= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
                registerForContextMenu(ib);
                openContextMenu(ib);
            }
         }
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add OnCreateContextMenuListener to the view:

```
    text.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo info) {
                menu.setHeaderTitle("Text context menu");
                menu.add(ContextMenu.NONE, MY_OPTION_CONTEXT_MENU, ContextMenu.NONE, "Some option");
            }
        });
```

In your activity view:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case MY_OPTION_CONTEXT_MENU:
            TextView v = (TextView) info.targetView;
            // more code here
            return true;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: thanks! also you can add the listener at the momment of the creation of view, in "getView" with customAdapter

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listview_with_icon, parent,  false);
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        final int m_pos = position;
                    label.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                ...             
            }
        });
        icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                ...             
            }
        });

        return(row);
    }
```